# How do I run PEAR not as root on MacOSX 10.7.4?

Tags: php, pear

PEAR has to be run via `sudo` on my system. This is annoying for two reasons. One, every time I want to use `pear` I have to do a `sudo`. Even if it's for something as simple as wanting to see how to use 'help'. The second reason is that it installs everything as `root` and I can't use simple programs installed via `pear` (like `phpdoc`) without having to sudo every time (which of course makes the generated documentation owned by root.

**How do I configure PEAR so that it can be usable?** I understand there might be security issues with not forcing PEAR to be run as root (i.e. I shouldn't be able to install to `/usr/lib/php/pear` without being root), but it's insane for me to have to use `sudo` to use the modules installed by PEAR.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my umask was set incorrectly to 007. This means that whenever I tried to use a package that pear had installed, I couldn't unless I was root. A better umask would be 006. This would allow everything installed to by root to be readable or executable (depending on the context).

You can set your umask in your .bashrc file in your home directory. Just add this line (or change the line that is incorrect):

```
umask 006
```

Hope this helps someone searching for an answer to this.